# The complement of a proper subgroup generates the whole group

Tags: group-theory

$H$ is subgroup of $G$ with $H$ not equal $G$.

Be $S=G-H$. I am being asked to prove that $\langle S \rangle=G$.

Some tip to solve this? I think in $S_3$ is possible but I can´t prove.

Comment: Hint: every element $h$ of $H$ can be expressed as $x^{-1}y$, where both $x$ and $y$ belong to $G - H$.

Comment: The title is a tad misleading...

Answer (score 6):

Hint. You have to use the hypothesis that $H\ne G$ and show that any element of $G$ can be written as a product of elements in $S$ or inverse thereof.

If $g\in S$, then of course $g\in\langle S\rangle$; if $g\in H$, pick an element $s\in S$; then $t=sg\notin H$ (why?); but $s^{-1}t=\dots$

Comment: $s^{-1}t=g\in H$ and $t=sg\notin H$ because s=G-H? , so pick  $s^-{1} \in S$ and $sg = t$ i can build g that  $\in H$, is that right?

Comment: @andre Almost. Since $s\notin H$, then $t=sg\notin H$; so $g=s^{-1}t\in\langle S\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. The complement $S$ contains at least one element. You can fix any one $s\in S$, and produce any $h\in H$ by a *single* multiplication involving $s$.

Comment: I understand this, in Z6 if i remove subgroup (0,2) or (0,2,4) , <1> and <3> generate G , but i cant put this in formal form. Every Group has at least one element that generate the group?

Comment: The hint is to not focus on generating the entire group, but on a single element; one you can show that every single element is in the group generated by $S$, then $S$ generates all of $G$. Now if our single element is in $S$, it is trivially in $\langle S\rangle$, so the hint focusses on the other possibility, namely an element$~h$ of $G-S=H$. If you try to write $h=sg$ with $s$ as in the answer, what can you say about $g$?

Comment: And for the last sentence of your comment: no, not every group has an element that generates the group; this is only so (by definition) for cyclic groups. Note that my answer does not say that the chose $s$ generates the entire group; the element $g$ above is also used.

Comment: I can say that, The interseccions of subgroups of G , except H, that contain a set S is the smallest subgroup G that contain S and is clear that subgroup H is not included in , So This interseccion is a subgroup too and generate G because contain finite products and inverses of elemnts of S.

Comment: Can't you just follow the hint? The "intersection of all subgroups containing $S$" description of $\langle S\rangle$ is not very useful if you have no idea what that set of subgroups might look like. But if you must use it, you need to show that the _only_ subgroup of $G$ containing  $S$ is $G$ itself. For this you might show that if $K$ is such a subgroup and $g\in G$ is arbitrary, then $g\in K$. But really, I don't think this point of view makes your task any easier.

Comment: Ok, see if this is correct. H has subgroups in that are single elements or no. Is H has no single elements, i can take elements in s , $x.y^-{1}$ and <s> generate G . If H has single elements, i need  group G to fix single elements that are not in set S, so s.g =h

Comment: @andre: I'm sorry, I can't understand a thing about what you are saying. My hint does not involve using _any_ subgroups at all (except $H$). You must reason that **any single element** $g$ of $G$ can be written as a product of one or more elements of $S$. Just think about what that means, and try to prove it separately for the cases $g\notin H$ and $g\in H$.